# Do I include 2 sets of W2's in mailed State return

Tags: united-states, taxes, marriage, virginia

I am filing my federal return as Married Joint and two state returns, one as married joint and one as married separate. This is due to one spouse living/working in the second state for part of the year. The state of Virginia is the state where only one spouse worked and I checked with their state laws and this is allowed.

Questions:
Do I include both spouse's W2's with that return or only the one with Virinia taxes witheld/paid since they will have the federal return in the envelope with it that shows both spouse's incomes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you only need to include W-2s with a state tax return if it shows withholding of that state's tax. So if only one W-2 shows Virginia tax withheld, only that one needs to be included with the Virginia tax return.